# Can ios keyboard extension include IAP?

Tags: ios-keyboard-extension

I've seen some keyboards on the iOS App Store that contain IAP like themes, backgrounds, etc. However, The Apple Review Guidelines (4.4.1) say that keyboard extensions must not "Include marketing, advertising, or in-app purchases;". I am considering creating my own extension but not sure whether I should introduce IAP or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the IAP is actually inside the container app not in the extension , for example swiftkey